# Keypad with Intel Galileo

Tags: python

I am doing a project using Intel Galileo. However, I have a problem with the 4x4 keypad. When I run this code, on line 6 appears an error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. How can I fix it?

From wiringx86 import GPIOGalileo as GPIO

```
class keypad():  # What kind of keyboard?
        def__init__ (self,4)
    self.KEYPAD =[
        [1,2,3,"A"],
        [4,5,6,"B"],
        [7,8,9,"C"],
        ["*",0,"#","D"]
                 ]
```

PS: If you have any code sample on Intel Galileo to input keypad keys, could you please show me? :)))

Comment: What are you trying to do with `def __init__(self, 4)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In python indentation is really important. I can see several wrong things in your code.

```
def __init__(self, 4)
```

this is wrong, you cannot just put a number in the constructor. If you want to set a default value for some parameter of the constructor you can do this as follow

```
def __init__(self, param=4):
```

You should also never forget the `:`.

This should then work:

```
class keypad():
    def __init__(self, param=4):
        self.KEYPAD =[[1,2,3,"A"],
                      [4,5,6,"B"],
                      [7,8,9,"C"],
                      ["*",0,"#","D"]]
```

But since I don't see any use for the parameter in the constructor you can simply remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, when I added ' :  ', the syntax error appeared. I would like to remind you that we are coding on Putty